# Java Swing resizing UI overlap elements

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jpanel

I have created a GUI with **NetBeans GUI Builder** and manually wrote some additional code.
I don't really know how to properly describe this problem, so please have a look at the picture below.

1. This is a default view, where you can notice the JTable that has been created inside a JPanel manually:

   ```
               jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

               TableModel model = db.populateJTable();
               JTable jTable1 = new JTable(model);
               jTable1.setModel(model);

               JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(jTable1);

               jPanel1.add(tableContainer);
               View.super.getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
               //View.super.pack();
               View.super.setVisible(true);
   ```

[image]

2. When I try to resize the window horizontally, all components react properly by resizing as specified, but the JTable just stay where rendered before, overlapping with other elements:

[image]
Can someone please tell me what is happening and how should I proceed?
many thanks

Comment: _I don't really know how to properly describe this problem_: post some code :-)

Comment: I posted the only code that I wrote relative to the GUI, all the rest is managed by NetBeans (houndreds of lines)

Comment: Instead of directly placing the table on the base panel. Add an extra panel and then place the table. That should help

Comment: This is like looking for a needle in a haystack. Without seeing the code, all we can give you is advice or wild guesses on what you may be doing wrong. Try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you are looking for a good answer.

Comment: Any decent Swing user is able to tell which component is which on your picture. The relevant information is actually the `LayoutManager`'s and the constraints that you have used for each container. Most likely you have used one incorrectly, causing the table not to move.

Comment: Don't let the GUI designer dicate your GUI design.

Answer (score 0):

A powerful solution: use [`Layout`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). They do all the job for you while resizing.

A good one is [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). If you need more complex layout, you can use the powerful [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

That if you want to design your layout manually. For me, I prefer using NetBeans 7.2.1 designer. It automatically configures the layout for you while designing them in the design window.

Comment: BoxLayout is powerful and more complex that GridBagLayout? Last I have heard, it's the other way around.